# how get the count of enum field items in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a field of type enum:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    class placeMenu(models.TextChoices):
        navar_menu_1="MN1", ("چایگاه هدر اول")
        navar_menu_2="MN2", ("جایگاه هدر دوم")
        navar_menu_3="MN3", ("جایگاه هدر سوم")
        footer_menu_1="FN1", ("جایگاه فوتر اول")
        footer_menu_2="FN2", ("جایگاه فوتر دوم")
        social = "SC1", ("شبکه های اجتماعی")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url=models.URLField(max_length=50)
    sort=models.IntegerField()
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=1)
    icon_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=True)
    icon_color=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=True)
    place_menu=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=placeMenu.choices)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How can I get count item with value enum?
My enum field has four values. And I want to get the count of each value Optimally.

Comment: Could you please share your model(s) involving this field?

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to have Group By aggregations using Django ORM, you can do the following:

**Case:** You want to count `place_menu` according to their respective choices and see how many times each has been used

To do that, you can do:

```
get_places = Menu.objects.all().values('place_menu').annotate(value_count=Count('place_menu')).values('place_menu', 'value_count').order_by()
```

You should get your desired result where you can see the count of each value.

Comment: thanks you
How can I display the names of the enums along with them?

Comment: place_menu should return that name, doesn't it?

Comment: thank you mr
The code worked correctly
How can I display the label?